# How to scrape Local Storage KEY/VALUES with R or Python (RVEST, HTTR, XHR, or something like that)

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, httr

I've been trying to scrape this page's Data https://data.anbima.com.br/debentures?page=1&size=2000&.

I easily could get that table usin rvest bs4 etc.

However i found that the JSON file that sources the table's data have others useful complementary information.

Then i found the XHR link in the browser inspection panel provides the access to the JSON file.

I've been using this link for several month, however in the last few weeks that link (https://data.anbima.com.br/debentures-bff/debentures?page=0&size=2000&field=&order=&) started to request for a authorization code (TOKEN). The issue is that this token changes every period of time or another criteria.

I explore i little more and figure-out that TOKEN is generated by a JS and is stored in a **Local Storage** inside somewhere in the page. I need this token to include as headers in the code...

My simple question is: How can I scrape that value with r or python?

PLEASE CHECK THE IMAGE BELOW

[LOCAL STORAGE VALUES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8uVa.png)

My simple question is: How can I scrape that value with r or python?

```
library(httr)
library(rlist)
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(V8)


resp<-GET("https://data.anbima.com.br/debentures?page=1&size=1499")
http_type(resp) 
http_error(resp)


query <- list(
  page="0",
  size="1470",
  field="",
  order=""
)
URL <- "https://data.anbima.com.br/debentures-bff/debentures"


resp<-GET(URL,
          c(
            # add_headers(Referer = "https://data.anbima.com.br/debentures?page=1&size=1470&"),
            add_headers(Authorization = "03AGdBq25HDdu4v2AzEjXJ_twI97EMrFlaNIcs3IuDHWzTFIp2mCXBqPaQPikuK7VRS3D7IC2v5briUdxPK3LpMPqrb1NoBqcXuI8gUkFdgVyNlObIdNzwQpVjcYASaW9N_gDx-M0SclFK54dDXHyRI7UVPAEQryV-1YSF6ebdJbY4BDr_eXRgMYe6UcK_Uh0YdfU1pMlcuU8O5dXKoRA-9GcX_AeaUxAUo5Mo_hQEGb0IPkPxojvEfgHvFdK0SQ4wgnmnJ0pcieO3h2exnJY1QxQd9sqqkfzdbGLaaCC7eNeWzXRAO3Yd9HtUciMclK612LfEm_ut89rtw8hSzlX3ZY6Vmo6zTvPT0WlMUrGLZ7syDEoDJKCi5xv6CSNgdAxqqqudEltDPUB7
")
            ),
            query=query)


js <- fromJSON(content(resp,as="text"))[[1]]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zwBM.png)

Comment: i found that the values are stored in the ldb files inside appdata... how can i access it?